# Uniqueness of reduced rank QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix with rank $r$. Then $A$ can be written as

$$A=QR$$

where $Q$ is $n\times r$ with orthonormal columns and $R$ is $r\times m$ upper triangular.

**Proof.** Apply the Gram–Schmidt process to the columns of $A$, discarding any column which can written as a linear combination of the previous columns. This produces orthonormal vectors $q_1,\dots,q_r$. By induction we see that the $j$th column of $A$ lies in the span of $q_1,\dots,q_{\min{(j,r)}}$ for $j=1,\dots, n$. This means that $A=QR$ with $Q,R$ having the desired properties.

Now the answer given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/225111) suggests that the decomposition above is unique if we require  positive leading entries in every row of $R$.

How can one prove this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The result holds when $r=m<n$.

Comment: Here is a proof when $r=m$.
Suppose $A=Q_1U_1=Q_2U_2$ where $Q_j$ is orthogonal and $U_j$ is upper triangular with positive elements in the diagonal. Then
$Q^*_2Q_1=U_2U^{-1}_1$. As $\operatorname{rank}(A)=m$, the range of $A$, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ coincide; hence $Q_1Q^*_1Q_2=Q_2$ since $Q_1Q^*_1$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $Q_1$. Therefore
$$Q^*_2Q_1Q^*_1Q_2=I_m$$
That is, $Q^*_2Q_1$ is an $m\times m$ orthogonal matrix. This means that 
$U_2U^{-1}_1=Q^*_2Q_1$ is an upper triangular and orthogonal matrix. This $U_2U^{-1}_1=I_m$

Comment: I don't think the result holds (uniqueness) if $A$ is no of full rank as there may be many ways to choose $r$ linearly independent columns from matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0):

For the $n\times n$ non-singular case, you can rely on uniqueness of the Cholesky decomposition. If $A=QR$ then $A^\top A = R^\top R$ is positive definite. I believe you can use a similar argument in your case.

Comment: Can I take the $r$ diagonal elements of $R$ to be positive in the reduced rank QR decomposition?

Comment: They need to be positive for uniqueness. If you don't have it initially with Gram-Schmidt, just multiply by an appropriate diagonal matrix $D$ : $A = QD^{-1}D R = Q_1 R_1$

Comment: Yes but the diagonal elements of $R$ could be zero no? Also I don't see how to adapt the argument. Could you provide more details?